# Python datetime strptime with calendar week number

Tags: python, datetime

According to resources, the method to transform a string that contains "year-week_number" (such as 2015-20) to a datetime object is the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2015-20", "%Y-%W")
```

However, this does not give me the correct result.  What I am getting is
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)

Moreover:

```
datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime("2015-20", "%Y-%W"). "%Y-%W")
```

actually returns "2015-00".

Is this just a bug or did I forget to do something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

> When used with the strptime() method, %U and %W are only used in calculations when the day of the week and the year are specified.

Given you are not specifying day of the week, the `%W` parameter is being ignored as per the documentation.

Add the weekday to whatever you want, I put Monday:

```
>>> datetime.strptime("2015-20-1", "%Y-%W-%w")
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 18, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Point 6. [of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)  is what's important here:

> When used with the strptime() method, %U and %W are only used in
>   calculations when the day of the week and the year are specified.

---

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime("2016-12-0", "%Y-%m-%w")
print "Week:"m datetime.strftime(date, "%W")

>>>Week: 48
```

Also, be aware of the small difference between `%W` and `%U`.